# Infinite loop on settheme()

Tags: android

I am trying to change the app theme from the fragment using `setTheme()` method of an activity. But somehow its looping forever while trying to change. Here is my `setTheme()` method calls.

```
//XYZ Fragment class

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (mThemeName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mode 1")) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        getActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_One);
    } else  {
        getActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_Two);
    }

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}     

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //binding object of this fragment
    binding = FragmentXYZBinding.inflate(inflater);

    binding.switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {

        if(isChecked){
            setTheme("Mode 2");
        }else {
            setTheme("Mode 1");
        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
}

public void setTheme(String name) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("ThemeName", name);
    editor.apply();

    // If i call this recreate() then it goes into infinite loop 
    // but without calling this I can't change theme on runtime
    //getActivity().recreate();
}
```

Any idea about what could be wrong in here ?

Comment: Set your theme inside oncreateview rather than onviewcreated

Comment: Thanks for your input. But if I call setTheme from oncreateView then, it does not change theme. It stays in the current theme without any changes.

Comment: Can you show me how you wrote it. It should work. Aldo you've literally called `if(IsChecked){
            setTheme("Mode 2");`  set theme here, so why would it not work?